# How to replace a triple for loop using the Java 8 streams API

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

I’m trying to navigate over 3 lists (nested triple for loop) and set some values based on a match.  Below is a class representation and also the triple for loops I’m iterating over and doing the setting based on a match.

My question is, how would I replace the loops included below, using the streams API?

I’m new to Java and trying to wrap my head around Java 8 features.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  thank you and have a wonderful day!

Listed below are the classes involved and the loops which I want to replace with the Java 8 streams API:

CLASSES:

```
class B {
  Long Id;
  Long x;
  String y;
  Long z;
}

class A {
  private  Long Id;
  private  List<B> bList;
}

class C {
  private  Long Id;
  private  List<Long> bIds;
  private  String y;
  private Long z;
}
```

NESTED FOR LOOPS:

```
  void f(List<A> aList, List<C> cList) {
    for(A a : aList) {
      List<B> bList= a.getBList();
      for(B b : bList) {
        for(C c : cList) {
          if(a.getId().equals(c.getId()) && c.getBIds().contains(b.getId())) {
            b.setZ(c.getZ());
            b.setY(c.getY());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have a working solution.  How do unambiguously, in a non-opinionated way quantify what "better" means so that someone could have a chance at responding to this?

Comment: 'lambdas are better' are a common refrain. That is, however, entirely incorrect. The vast majority of existing loops are fine, certainly if they look fairly simple and are easy enough to read, which your existing loop is. An equivalent in lambda-ese might _also_ be fine, but might  very well not. As a rule, they aren't: Lambda-based code lacks 3 transparencies (they aren't control-flow, (checked) exception, and mutable local var transparent, but loops usually are, so there's a bunch of friction there). Only if that is irrelevant can lambdas even _begin_ to try to be as good.

Comment: Where lambas shine are where either [A] your current code is a hot mess, [B] you kinda need more abstraction than you have, and/or [C] you completely redesign it all, and e.g. intend to pass the operation that needs to be done around, instead of passing the data around. Sometimes that's cleaner. Lambdas help _a lot_ for such a redesign. But, such a redesign encompasses a much, _much_ larger segment of the codebase, it's not just 'redesign this triple nested for loop'.

Comment: Finally, note that a triple nested loop remains just as triple nested if you replace things with lambdas. There can be ways to eliminate a nesting level or two but 'use lambdas!' is not how you go about it.

Comment: Tip: A contrived semi-realistic scenario makes for more readable code examples.

Comment: @possum. Thanks for your reply!  I really appreciate it.  I should have phrased my post better.  This is purely for educational purposes.  I’m trying to learn java 8 features like streams, predicates etc and this was a loop that I thought would be a good candidate for converting to use streams.  I guess "better" is too vague.  Maybe "different" would be more apt.  I'm just trying to wrap my head around streams.  Thanks once again!

Comment: @rzwitserloot, thanks so much for all your insights!  This has really helped me understand the pros/cons of lambdas!